# How do I remove an article from Scopus indexing?

Tags: journals, retraction

Due to some technical mistakes, I removed my published article from a journal. But the article was already indexed by Scopus. I need to remove the article from Scopus indexing database as well. Could I get some guidance in this regard?

Comment: What do you mean technical mistake? Do you mean that a retraction was issued?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you [contact them directly](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14837/supporthub/scopus/)

And explain why they should remove the article, with actual proof that it's no longer available in the journal in question.